# Does Windows 8 contain a boot loader?

Tags: windows-8, bootloader

Does Windows 8 come with a boot loader?  Like Lilo or Grub?  Or do we still have to use a third party one?

Comment: All operating systems have a bootloader, this just happens to be a custom one that isn't publicly available.  Do you mean an *open* bootloader?

Comment: @Shinrai a boot loader that allows us to have more than one operative system and select which one we want. So I don't need to re-install Grup after I install windows-8.

Comment: The Windows bootloader will happily accommodate multiple operating systems.  (They just have to be other versions of Windows.)  I'm not trying to be pedantic, just trying to make you aware that it's important to be clear about this because the meaning could be confusing.  A perfectly valid answer to your question would be "Yes, all modern operating systems have bootloaders." but that's not really addressing what I think you actually want to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows 8 has an custom boot loader that locks the pre-OS environment using UEFI. LILO nd GRUB are FOSS undertaking and Microsoft uses a custom(not a third party) boot loader.

Windows 8 boot loader uses UEFI while grub and lilo will run any OS. The Windows 8 bootloader is a lot more secure too.

[image]